# How do I make a React Subscription function reactive?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to implement Pagination for my Meteor App using React and mongo. I've done this by passing a limit prop to my subscription function like so:

```
export default class BookListTable extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
var limit = this.props.LimitProp
limit = parseInt(limit) || 5;
this.state =   {
subscription: {
booksData: Meteor.subscribe("allBooks", {limit: limit})
}
}
///// rest of component
```

This works great the first time the react component renders but when I update the props nothing changes. I expect the component to re-render with the updated limit property - however this doesn't happen. What am I missing?

Any related info around pagination appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update the property LimitProp, the component re-renders with LimitProp changed but the constructor is not invoked again. *You only copy the value of the LimitProp to limit and then use it when the component is created*, so the state (suscription) is not updated when it changes. I think that you should use **componentDidMount**.

[Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)